# What is the best time of the year to ask a question?

Tags: discussion, statistics

I wonder if there is any data on whether questions receive more attention in some months, while less in some others.
Is it better to ask during Christmas or the summer break, at the beginning or at the end of the semester?

Comment: Christmas is during the summer break, mate.

Comment: It depends a lot on what you mean by best time. (Most views? Highest percentage of posts posted at that time answered?) Probably you can find such statistics [using SEDE](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info). Maybe there already are some queries for this purpose. Maybe you could try to modify some of the existing once. Related posts: [Question and answer activity on StackExchange: Interactive and customized edition](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213603), [Number of answers/views/votes depends on hour of posting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2133).

Comment: Somebody even tried to find the best part of week to post depending on the tag: [Depending on the tag is there a possibility to know on which days and hours are there more answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3865). BTW I think that ([meta-tag:statistics]) and perhaps ([meta-tag:data-explorer]) might be suitable tags for your question.

Comment: Using SEDE is above my abilities... I ran http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/155865/best-time-to-ask-questions-on-stackexchange-more-likely-to-get-an-answer with my userID, but it showed practically no difference.

Comment: @domotorp This is probably rather naive question, but since you linked to query for SO, I will ask anyway: You know that you have to [switch site to MathOverflow](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/155865/best-time-to-ask-questions-on-stackexchange-more-likely-to-get-an-answer?UserId=955), right? (Apart from that, I think that questions from single user might be rather small sample to draw some relevant conclusions from them.)

Comment: I hope that somebody with better SQL skills will try to give you some more useful data, but results of my (very simplistic) experiments are [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2016/10/7).